# Determining if Excel cell content exceeds default size in Python

Tags: python, excel

We have scripts that will write data to Excel and then automatically create a PDF report from that Excel file. On some occasions, due to the length of a cell, its contents will be cut off as seen below.

[image]

I'm trying to write some code that will adjust the cell height after all the data is written to Excel but before the PDF is created. I have a Python script that will word wrap, double the height, and center the vertical alignment provided that I specify the row number (i.e. 10 & 11)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

def main():
    CellAdjust()

def CellAdjust():
    affected_rows = [10,11]
    no_of_sheets = excel.Sheets.Count
    for each_sheet in range(no_of_sheets):
        for row in affected_rows:
            excel.Worksheets(each_sheet+1).Rows(row).VerticalAlignment = 2
            excel.Worksheets(each_sheet+1).Rows(row).WrapText = True
            excel.Worksheets(each_sheet+1).Rows(row).RowHeight = 31.5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

I don't want to do it to all rows because it ruins the resulting appearance of the remaining fields. So is there a way to determine if a cell's content is beyond the default width, and if so apply the function? Or is there a better way to automate this?

Comment: It's not perfect, but you can manually find the default size and compare to the digit count of each number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use your cell object's **Value** method to grab the value of the cell, then check its width. If it's too wide to be displayed, then call your CellAdjust function. You will probably have to play around with the width a bit to find the optimal number to use.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would take atleast a little manual guesswork.. Is there a more efficient way to check the contents of all the cells in the workbook without using a for loop and iterating through each cell?